# Cambiar dinámicamente imagen de fondo (Ionic 4)

Tags: ionic4

Hago una aplicación en Ionic 4, y quiero poner imagen alusiva de fondo de acuerdo al icono de clima de la api.  Open weather map. Funciona CASI todo perfecto, pero...

**No logro que aparezca la imagen de fondo**

Imagen e icono, tienen el mismo nombre, lo armo en el archivo ts.

```
this.image_backg = ‘http://www………………..’+…+nombre del icono.png
```

(el valor que toma es el correcto, lo muestro en pantalla, y si navego web con ese valor, me muestra la imagen perfecto)

Archivo html:

```
<ion-content no-bounce class="ion-padding" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image_backg + ')'}">
```

Otros datos:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.11.0 
 Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
 cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

 Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0

System:
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android)
   NodeJS : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm : 6.12.1
   OS : Windows 8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, de la siguiente manera:

agregado al archivo scss:

```
ion-content {
    --background: none;
}
```

en el archivo html:

```
<ion-content 
[style.background-image]="'url(' + image_backg + ')'" 
[style.background-size]="'cover'" 
[style.background-repeat]="'no-repeat'"
>
```

en el archivo ts:

```
  this.image_backg = '../../assets/imgs/xxxxxxx.jpg'
o 
  this.image_backg = 'https://www.........'
```